# Jquery - select all element with specific class and change text based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, substring

I have this HTML:

```js
$('.p_text').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).data('text');
  $(this).text(txt.substring(0, 20) + '...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="p_text" data-text="2 Pieces Sets Tracksuit Men New Brand Autumn Winter Hooded Sweatshirt +Drawstring Pants Male Stripe Patchwork Hoodies Bigsweety">2 Pieces Sets Tracksuit Men New Brand Autumn ...</span>
<span class="p_text" data-text="2019 brand casual plaid luxury plus size long sleeve slim fit men shirt spring social dress shirts mens fashions jersey 41607">2019 brand casual plaid luxury plus size long sleeve slim fit men shirt ...</span>
```

```
    <span class="p_text" data-text="2 Pieces Sets Tracksuit Men New Brand Autumn Winter Hooded Sweatshirt +Drawstring Pants Male Stripe Patchwork Hoodies Bigsweety">2 Pieces Sets Tracksuit Men New Brand Autumn ...</span>
<span class="p_text" data-text="2019 brand casual plaid luxury plus size long sleeve slim fit men shirt spring social dress shirts mens fashions jersey 41607">2019 brand casual plaid luxury plus size long sleeve slim fit men shirt ...</span>
```

I need to select all spans with class `p_text` and limit inner Text to 20 characters but I need to take text from attribute `data-text` first

I tried:

```
$('.p_text').each(function(){
   
var txt = $(this).data('text');
$(this).text(txt.substring(0,20) + '...');
 });
```

but it changes the only text in the first span and then gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

How I can limit text in every span element with class p_text ?

Comment: I made a snippet of your code.  Please update to explain why that is not working.

Comment: hi, sorry its works when I change class... must be used the same class everywhere. I will delete question

Answer (score 1):

There is also a CSS only way to do this using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` which makes it responsive. Resize the `div` in the snippet below.

```css
.truncate {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 100px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="truncate">2 Pieces Sets Tracksuit Men New Brand Autumn Winter Hooded Sweatshirt +Drawstring Pants Male Stripe Patchwork Hoodies Bigsweety</div>
  <div class="truncate">
    2019 brand casual plaid luxury plus size long sleeve slim fit men shirt spring social dress shirts mens fashions jersey 41607
  </div>
</div>
```